# progress bar not progressing

Tags: c#, multithreading, progress-bar

I have a program which is updating a table in sqlserver, I have a form which I want to show the progress of this, the progress bar is incrementing but this is not being displayed. do i need to use background worker for this? example of what im doing

```
public void updateTable(string tableName)
{
  // con is an instance of my form to access progressbar
  con.progressBar1.Minimum = 1;
  con.progressBar1.Step = 1;
  string dbQuery = "select summet from someting"

  con.progressBar1.Maximum = address.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
  MessageBox.Show("progress bar max " + con.progressBar1.Maximum);

   foreach (DataRow LonLat in address.Tables[0].Rows)
   {
       con.progressBar1.PerformStep();
       MessageBox.Show(con.progressBar1.Value.ToString()); // this is incrementing
       //plus updating table 

   }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**, yes. If you do it from the main thread you won't see the progress bar update.

**Long answer:**

Whenever you modify the user interface from a piece of your code that's translated into a "message" into the window message queue that will get that message and update the UI accordingly in the main thread.

However, since the main thread is busy handling your piece of code it doesn't have the "time" to actually update the user interface, and only when your process is done, it's free to update the user interface. That's why you see the progress bar going from 0% to 100% without any intermediate steps.

**What you should do:**

What you wanna do is put the work into a background worker, that way the main thread is free to attend UI update requests... that's, by the way, a standard practice if you wanna keep the UI responsive.

Comment: Cordoba, Great explanation, It would be really nice with a sample code which divert the operation with a new thread and main thread updating UI element.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use Background Worker, however it might not help, we would need to see bindings and everything else, to use background worker use something like this:

```
Window.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            con.progressBar1.PerformStep();
        }
```

Comment: Please note Window is reference to window Progress bar is located at! so i guess its con.Dispatcher...

Comment: BackgroundWorker has specific support for updating progress bars; you just need to call the update progress method and then attach an event handler to the appropriate event.  If you do that there is no need to marshal to the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to use background worker

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
    {
     // your code goes here
       }
 worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (q, ea) =>
    {
      }
 worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens if we cannot use a BackgroundWorker. I have a form with a progress bar whose only job is to accept a command to PerformStep, from some other form that opens it, and the form must simply do that. Both forms are in the GUI thread. 
Nevertheless I don't get a consistent behavior from the progressbar. In the code below the progressbar is always one step behind than what its Value Property Signifies:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      private readonly int m_numOfSteps;

      public Form1(int numOfSteps)
      {
         m_numOfSteps = numOfSteps;
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void Form1_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
      {
         progressBar1.Step = (int)Math.Ceiling( 100.0 / m_numOfSteps );
      }

      public void DoStep(string msg)
      {
         progressBar1.PerformStep();
         label1.Text = msg;
         label2.Text = String.Format( "{0}%", progressBar1.Value  );
         label1.Refresh();
         label2.Refresh();
      }
   }

   public partial class Form2 : Form
   {
      public Form2()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
      {
         using( Form1 f = new Form1( 3 ) )
         {
            f.Show();
            f.Refresh();
            Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
            f.DoStep( "AAAA" );
            Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
            f.DoStep( "BBBB" );
            Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
            f.DoStep( "CCCC" );
            Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
         }
      }
   }
```